# Land Surface Temperature in GEE: ,Creating a Chart with correct values

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart, geemap, land-surface-temperature

I have this code below for creating an LST for my region. Then, I create a chart with the mean values. But code gives the LST values in the chart in negative from the range -250 to -293. Now I do not know how and what in the code to change for correct results.
Code Link
https://code.earthengine.google.com/49dac1b33557fee0afb0c8d1c0ae31cb

```
//vis params
var vizParams = {
  bands: ['B5', 'B6', 'B4'],
  min: 642,
  max: 3307,
  gamma: [1, 0.9, 1.1]
};

var vizParams2 = {
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};

//load the collection:
var col = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1').filterMetadata ('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 5)
    .filterDate('2011-01-01','2011-12-31')
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .map(function(image){return image.clip(geometry)});

print('collection', col);
Map.centerObject(geometry)
//imagen reduction

var image = col.median();
//print('image', image);

Map.addLayer(image, vizParams2);

//median
var ndvi1 = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']).rename('NDVI');
var ndviParams = {min: 0.10554729676864096, max: 0.41295681063122924, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};

//print('ndvi1', ndvi1);

//individual LST images

var col_list = col.toList(col.size());

var LST_col = col_list.map(function (ele) {
  
  var date = ee.Image(ele).get('system:time_start');

  var ndvi = ee.Image(ele).normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']).rename('NDVI');
  
  // find the min and max of NDVI
  var min = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  }).values().get(0));
  
  var max = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  }).values().get(0));
  
  var fv = (ndvi.subtract(min).divide(max.subtract(min))).pow(ee.Number(2)).rename('FV');
  
  var a= ee.Number(0.004);
  var b= ee.Number(0.986);
  
  var EM = fv.multiply(a).add(b).rename('EMM');

  var image = ee.Image(ele);

  var LST = image.expression(
    '(Tb/(1 + (0.00115* (Tb / 1.438))*log(Ep)))-273.15', {
      'Tb': image.select('B6_VCID_2').multiply(0.1),
      'Ep': fv.multiply(a).add(b)
  });

  return ee.Algorithms.If(min, LST.set('system:time_start', date).float().rename('LST'), 0);

}).removeAll([0]);

LST_col = ee.ImageCollection(LST_col);

print("LST_col", LST_col);

/////////////////

Map.addLayer(ndvi1, ndviParams, 'ndvi');

//select thermal band 10(with brightness tempereature), no calculation 
var thermal= image.select('B6_VCID_2').multiply(0.1);

var b10Params = {min: 200, max: 400, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};

Map.addLayer(thermal, b10Params, 'thermal');

// find the min and max of NDVI
var min = ee.Number(ndvi1.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));

//print('min', min );

var max = ee.Number(ndvi1.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));

//print('max', max);

//fractional vegetation
var fv = (ndvi1.subtract(min).divide(max.subtract(min))).pow(ee.Number(2)).rename('FV'); 

//print('fv', fv);

//Map.addLayer(fv);

//Emissivity
var a= ee.Number(0.004);
var b= ee.Number(0.986);
var EM = fv.multiply(a).add(b).rename('EMM');

var imageVisParam3 = {min: 0.9865619146722164, max:0.989699971371314};

//Map.addLayer(EM, imageVisParam3,'EMM');

//LST in Celsius Degree bring -273.15
//NB: In Kelvin don't bring -273.15
var LST = col.map(function (image){

  var date = image.get('system:time_start');
  
  var LST = image.expression(
    '(Tb/(1 + (0.00115* (Tb / 1.438))*log(Ep)))-273.15', {
    'Tb': thermal.select('B6_VCID_2'),
    'Ep':EM.select('EMM')
  }).float().rename('LST');
  
  return LST.set('system:time_start', date);
  
});

//print(LST);

Map.addLayer(LST, {min: 22, max: 40, palette: [
'040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
'0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
'3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
]},'LST');

print(
      ui.Chart.image.series({
        imageCollection: LST_col, 
        region: geometry, 
        reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
        scale: 30, // nominal scale Landsat imagery 
        xProperty: 'system:time_start' // default
      }));

//export NDMI
/* 
var export_Collection = LST_col.select (['LST']).toBands();
// As a "flattened" image
print("export_Collection map", export_Collection);
Export.image.toDrive ({
   image: export_Collection, 
   description: 'LST_collection', 
   scale: 30,
   region: geometry,
  maxPixels:1e13
}); 
*/
// As a reduced Image
var export_Image = LST_col.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());
print("export_Image map", export_Image);
Export.image.toDrive ({
   image: export_Image, 
   description: 'LST_image', 
   scale: 30,
   region: geometry,
  maxPixels:1e13
  
});
```

Comment: " If you have not applied for Earth Engine access, you can submit an application here. Note: the registration process may take several days and not all applications are approved. " when I click that link

Comment: Your brightness temperatures are wrong calculated. However, you also need other corrections for adequate visualization. Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your brightness temperatures are wrong calculated (see "Conversion to Top of Atmosphere Brightness Temperature" in [this document](https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/using-usgs-landsat-level-1-data-product)). You need following correction (parameters were obtained from metadata of images; see properties in whatever image of image collection) for getting correct results (K1 = 666.0900268554688, K2 = 1282.7099609375, RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_B6_VCID_2 = 0.03720499947667122, RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_B6_VCID_2 = 3.1628000736236572):

```
  var Tb = image.expression(
    '1282.7099609375 / log ((666.0900268554688/(0.03720499947667122*L + 3.1628000736236572)) + 1 )', {
    'L': image.select('B6_VCID_2')
  });

  var LST = image.expression(
    '(Tb/(1 + (0.00115* (Tb / 1.438))*log(Ep)))-273.15', {
      'Tb': Tb,
      'Ep': fv.multiply(a).add(b)
  });
```

Above correction was included in [complete code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ddf43a1f02b3bb478a153cd7df9334ac) and, after running it in GEE code editor, I got following result for an arbitrary area including Islamabad.

[image]

However, you also need other corrections for adequate visualization.